# Seria interessante reescrever o motivo de fechamento "baseado em opinião"?

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento

Já presenciei várias perguntas que acabaram sendo fechadas pelo motivo:

> **marcada como pendente** como principalmente baseada em opiniões por ...
>
> Várias perguntas boas geram algum grau de opinião com base na experiência de especialistas, mas as respostas a esta pergunta tenderão a ser quase que completamente baseadas em opiniões e não em fatos, referências ou experiência específica. Conheça as regras na central de ajuda e edite a pergunta para que fique adequada.

Mas nem sempre o problema remete-se apenas à opinião de cada um, mas também aos requisitos do projeto. Algumas perguntas que perguntam, por exemplo, "qual a melhor forma de implementar X" acabam sendo fechadas como baseadas em opinião onde possivelmente a resposta depende mais dos requisitos do projeto do que da opinião propriamente dita.

A título de exemplo:

- [Onde se codifica as regras de negócio no framework Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/371372/5878)

Poderíamos, então, reescrever o motivo de fechamento de forma que englobe também uma descrição de que as respostas poderiam variar de projeto para projeto dependendo dos requisitos de cada um?

Por exemplo:

> **marcada como pendente** por não possuir uma resposta canônica por ...
>
> Várias perguntas boas geram algum grau de opinião com base na experiência de especialistas, mas as respostas a esta pergunta tenderão a ser quase que completamente baseadas em opiniões ou dependem quase que exclusivamente dos requisitos do projeto e, assim, não possuem uma resposta canônica, que não seja apenas um reflexo de preferências pessoais. Conheça as regras na central de ajuda e edite a pergunta para que fique adequada.

Comment: Eu faria uma mistura: manteria o início "*marcada como pendente como principalmente baseada em opiniões*" (já que, mesmo tendo os requisitos, ainda sim podem existir divergências de opinião) e usaria o texto no qual vc acrescentou "*ou dependem quase que exclusivamente dos requisitos do projeto*". Acho que "resposta canônica" pode confundir especialmente usuários mais novos, que não estão familiarizados com o termo (e que *geralmente* são os que mais colocam esse tipo de pergunta).

Comment: @hkotsubo Consegue postar a sugestão como resposta?

Comment: Será que o motivo escolhido não é errado? Será que a pergunta não é ampla? Não fora de tópico? Ou será que a pergunta não deveria permanecer aberta? Isso é algo pra se discutir. A discussão é boa. Não sei se podemos mudar a descrição (se for muito importante podemos pedir pros devs, que alias tenho foto com um deles agora :P)

Answer (score 10):

Minha sugestão é manter o texto da primeira linha ("*marcada como pendente como principalmente baseada em opiniões*"), pois mesmo tendo todos os requisitos de um projeto, ainda sim podem existir opiniões diferentes sobre como atender tais requisitos.

Usando o seu exemplo: "*qual a melhor forma de implementar X*". Mesmo se a pergunta listar todos os requisitos, ainda sim a pergunta poderá ser baseada em opiniões, já que existem várias formas diferentes de atender um mesmo requisito, então não vejo razão para mudar o motivo do fechamento.

Além disso, mudar o motivo para "*não tem uma resposta canônica*" pode mais confundir do que ajudar, já que usuários mais novos não estão familiarizados com o termo, e estes são os que *geralmente* fazem perguntas deste tipo. De qualquer forma, mesmo se for um usuário mais "veterano" e que sabe o que é uma resposta canônica, o motivo atual ("baseado em opiniões") já me parece adequado.

---

De qualquer forma, acho válido colocar na descrição que a resposta pode variar conforme os requisitos, então o texto ficaria assim:

> **marcada como pendente** como principalmente baseada em opiniões por ...
>
> Várias perguntas boas geram algum grau de opinião com base na experiência de especialistas, mas as respostas a esta pergunta tenderão a ser quase que completamente baseadas em opiniões ou dependem quase que exclusivamente dos requisitos do projeto e, assim, não possuem uma resposta canônica, que não seja apenas um reflexo de preferências pessoais. Conheça as regras na central de ajuda e edite a pergunta para que fique adequada.